# How to properly include boost module with cmake find_package?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

to find regular boost module, the cmake code is quite simple

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(win32)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options)

add_executable(win32  main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(win32 PRIVATE fmt::fmt Boost::program_options)
```

But If I intent to find header-only module like `boost::lexical_cast`, `find_package` fails with error message:

```
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
CMake Warning at C:/Users/isudfv/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/231.8109.80/bin/cmake/win/x64/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2218 (message):
  No header defined for lexical_cast; skipping header check (note:
  header-only libraries have no designated component)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/Vcpkg/installed/x64-windows-static/share/boost/vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake:11 (_find_package)
  C:/Program Files/Vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:806 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Users/isudfv/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/231.8109.80/bin/cmake/win/x64/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: lexical_cast) (found version "1.81.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/isudfv/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/231.8109.80/bin/cmake/win/x64/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Users/isudfv/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/231.8109.80/bin/cmake/win/x64/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2377 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  C:/Program Files/Vcpkg/installed/x64-windows-static/share/boost/vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake:11 (_find_package)
  C:/Program Files/Vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:806 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/isudfv/Desktop/tmp/win32/cmake-build-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
FAILED: build.ninja
```

There's a solution that said I should use `target_include_directories`. But it makes the cmake code less unified.

Did I miss anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the warning message, **header-only** Boost libraries shouldn't be specified in COMPONENTS for `find_package(Boost)`. Without COMPONENTS,

```
find_package(Boost)
```

will search all header-only libraries automatically. For obtain include directory for that libraries, link with `Boost::boost` target:

```
target_link_libraries(win32 PRIVATE Boost::boost)
```

There is also `Boost::headers` target, which means effectively the same as `Boost::boost` one.

More information could be found in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html).